# selecting dataframe columns from names in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` with column names A .. Z. I have another list, `L1 = [A, D, G, Y]`. How do i create a new pandas dataframe `df2` with only columns A,D,G,Y selected from the original `df1`?

I tried the following approaches:

```
df2 = df1[L1]
```

but get an error

```
"KeyError: None of [Index ([(''A'',),(''D'',) ...<snip>... are in the [columns]"
```

If i try something like

```
df2 = df1[L1[0]]
```

then it works correctly i.e it gives me `df2` which consists only of column A.

Any idea what is missing in the first method? the second method of enumerating manually is tedious.
Thanks.

Comment: try this `L1 = ['A', 'D', 'G', 'Y']`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have a list of tuples.   Try `c,_ = zip(*L1);` `df2 = df1[c]`, unpacking that list of tuples into a list of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a list of tuples in L1.

Let's unpack that list tuples into a list of columns, c:

```
c, _ = zip(*L1)
df2 = df1[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

I created columns like you said, but i'm not seeing an error, can you show how yours differs from this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   W   X   Y   Z
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24


df1[L1]                                                                                                                                                                             

   A  D  G   Y
1  2  5  8  25
```

Comment: So my list was created from the values of a dataframe using L1 = df3.values.tolist() where df3 was a 1-column df whose values were A, D, G and Y

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my response to oppressionslayer, i had created L1 from the values in another dataframe:

```
df3 = [A, D, G, Y]
```

After seeing Scott Boston's answer, i realized that i can avoid the tupling if instead of

```
L1 = df3.values.tolist()
```

I could simply do

```
df2 = df1[df3[0]]
```

i get the subsetting i was looking for.